# ¿diferencencia entre dos horas usando momentjs formato hh:mm A?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

quiero usar la function diff de momentjs para obtener la diferencia entre dos horas formato AM/PM,

para mostrar en tiempo real la diferencia, o el lapso de tiempo de una hora a otra.

pero obtengo resultados como -47640000. ó -600000.

y lo que espero es esto:

ejemplo 1:

12:00 PM

01:00 PM

EL RESULTADO SERIA 01:00 (hh:mm).

ejemplo: 2:

07:40 AM

08:45 AM

EL RESULTADO SERIA 01:05 (hh:mm)

mi codidgo js:

```
$(".tiempotl").on("change keyup", function() {

    var hr1=$("#newHrEntrada").val();
    var hr2=$("#newHrSalida").val();

    var hrentrada = moment(hr1, 'hh:mm A');
    var hrsalida = moment(hr2, 'hh:mm A');

    console.log("hora entrada: ",hrentrada)

    console.log("hora salida: ",hrsalida)

    var tlhr =hrentrada.diff(hrsalida);
 
    console.log("tiempo total es igual:"+tlhr);
 
})
```

Comment: Probaste dando formato al intervalo? `moment().format('hh:mm')`

Comment: no estoy obteniendo el resultado esperado, quiero obtener el resultado en hh:mm, pero no sé que funcion más debo usar. o que tengo mal.

Comment: No tienes nada malo, solo que ese resultado esta en milisegundos. Podrias hacer tu mismo la conversion a minutos y horas, o buscar un metodo que convierta de milisegundos a ese formato

Comment: Aca hay un ejemplo en inglés, no se si te pueda ayudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816872/how-can-i-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mi soluccion fue hacer una consulta ajax, pues no sé si sea la mejor opcion,

pero funciona perfectamente.

> html

```
   <!--HORA ENTRADA-->
<input type='text' class="form-control horas" name="inputHrEntrada" id="HrEntrada" placeholder="00:00 .." required>


<!--HORA SALIDA-->
<input type='text' class="form-control horas" name="inputHrSalida" id="HrSalida" placeholder="00:00 .." required>

<!--TIEMPO TL-->
<input type='text' class="form-control" name="inputTmpTl" id="TmpTl" placeholder="TIEMPO TOTAL" readonly>
```

> js

```
$(".horas").on("change keyup", function() {
    var hr1=$("#HrEntrada").val();
    var hr2=$("#HrSalida").val();

    if (hr1!='' && hr2!='') {

        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("hrentrada1", hr1);
        datos.append("hrsaldia2", hr2);

        $.ajax({

            url:"ajax/Enfriamiento.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(respuesta){

                console.log("resp: ",respuesta);

                $("#TmpTl").val(respuesta);



            }

        });
    }
})
```

archivo PHP AJAX:

```
<?php

class AjaxDiferenciaHrs{

    /**DIFERENCIA DE HORAS */
    public $hrentrada;
    public $hrsalida;
    public function showtlhr(){

        $hr1 = $this->hrentrada;
        $hr2 = $this->hrsalida;

        $hora1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $hr1);
        $hora2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', $hr2);
        $interval = $hora1->diff($hora2);
        $tiemptl=$interval->format('%H:%I');

        echo json_encode($tiemptl);
    }

}//fin class AjaxEnfriamiento


/**MOSTRAR DIFERENCIA ENTRE HORA ENTRADA Y HORA SALIDAD*/
if (isset($_POST["hrentrada1"]) && isset($_POST["hrsaldia2"])) {

    $showhrtl = new AjaxEnfriamiento();
    $showhrtl -> hrentrada = $_POST["hrentrada1"];
    $showhrtl -> hrsalida = $_POST["hrsaldia2"];
    $showhrtl -> showtlhr();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
var entryHour = moment('08:45 am', 'hh:mm A');
var exitHour = moment('09:45 am', 'hh:mm A');

var duration = moment.duration(exitHour.diff(entryHour)).asHours();

console.log(duration);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

En esta línea a continuación lo que realizamos es obtener la duración de la diferencia entre la hora de entrada y la hora de salida como horas, también podrías utilizar otros métodos si quieres el valor en otro formato, como `asMinutes()`, `asDays()`, `asWeeks()`, etc

```
var duration = moment.duration(exitHour.diff(entryHour)).asHours();
```

Comment: pero si fuera 08:45 am y 09:46 am el resultado seria 1.0166666666666666 y lo que necesito es 01:01 (01:01)

Answer (score 0):

Como lo mencionan en la [documentación](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/), puedes apoyarte con [`moment-duration-format`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-duration-format) para formatear de una forma más comprensiva los [durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

```js
var entryHour = moment('08:45 am', 'hh:mm A');
var exitHour = moment('09:46 am', 'hh:mm A');

var duration = exitHour.diff(entryHour);

console.log(moment.duration(duration, 'milliseconds'));
console.log(moment.duration(duration, 'milliseconds').format("hh:mm"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment-duration-format@2.3.2/lib/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```